# Boxes with cross instead of text in Flash-site on Raspberry Pi

Tags: flash, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

My kid is a big fan of an educational game website running on Adobe Flash (mathletics.com).  So, I got Rapsberry Pi 2 and set up Flash on it (using PepperFlash).  Flash is now running OK and I can enter and navigate this site and other Flash-based sites.
But, when entering the math quizz of the site, the pictures and animations are looking good but the text is not legible.  the letters are not displayed, instead I get small boxes with an X.
This is quite strange because I am able to read and navigate the website menus (also in Flash);  only the text of the quizz is broken ...

I downloaded PepperFlash 19.0.0.185 and my /etc/chromium-browser/default reads:
`CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=19.0.0.185"`

Can you help ?

Fabien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that boxes with crosses are displayed when a particular font is missing, in this case it looked like Arial. Anyway Debian has a Windows font pack, install it with

sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Then restart. You may need to rebuild the font cache with

fc-cache -fv

Although I'm not sure. Hope that helps

Russ